# Having problems using ObservableCollection's .First() directive

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection

I have a segment in my code, where I want to scan a list of items, to see if the user entered a new item. To accomplish this, I am using a ObservableCollection items, and executing it's .First directive, since it seems they took away my beloved .Find, from working with List.

This is how I used to be able to find said element, but it's throwing an exception now, can anyone please give this a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?
I would prefer to avoid performing the Foreach method od doing this, but unless I can find what's wrong here, I wont have an option...

```
Sources src = new Sources() { Entry = this.viewModel.MyCase.Source, RecordCategory = (int)RecordCatagory.Supplies };
//If there is no matching element found we need to create it.
if (this.viewModel.SourcesList.First(x => x.Entry.Equals(src.Entry)) == null)
{
    this.viewModel.SourcesRepo.AddItem(src);
}
```

Comment: "it's throwing an exception" - what specific exception is it throwing?

Comment: It's me being an idiot... I just realized the exception was telling me the element was not found, and I reazlised I should be using a try instead of if... my bad. I will answer it. Thanks for checking in on it! your question actually helped me confirm I was being a fool! HA!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was being an idiot... 
The exception "Sequence contains no matching elements" (don't ask why I didn't catch that sooner, not enough coffee, and was not expecting an exception) was telling me there were no elements found. More or less doing exactly what I wanted. But since I was hoping that it would return a null result and not throw an exception my logic was all wrong. I will change my if into a try, and catch this specific ...no matching elements.. exception. 
Just as an afterthought, is there any way to have it behave like a List and return a null result?

Thanks again.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will return a null if nothing matches